# Java ini without spaces

Tags: java, configuration, ini

I have attempted to use ini4j and inieditor to alter from java an ini configuration file. Unfortunately, both libraries rewrite the file putting spaces besides the = sign...

This breaks that C library it is attempting to configure.

```
#This is a sample of what I get:
[root]
role = administrator
last_login = 2003-05-16

#This is what I need:
[root]
role=administrator
last_login=2003-05-16
```

I saw that ini4j has something named FancyIniFormatter which apparently does just that but I was unable to find proper documentation on the usage... http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/ini4j/ini4j/0.4.0/ini4j-0.4.0.jar!/org/ini4j/addon/FancyIniFormatter.class?classDetails=ok

I am hoping to do this natively from the library but I can always load up the file and perform a regex operation but if I can avoid it that would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ini4j formater is based on [Config](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/ini4j/Config.html). In this config the separator is set to char '=', but in the class [IiniFormatter](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/ini4j/spi/IniFormatter.html) you have another declaration of separator as string " = ". This type is used when `Config#isStrictOperator` is set to false.

```
Config config = new Config();
  config.setStrictOperator(true);

IniFormmater formater = IniFormmater.newInstance(out, config);
```

Comment: How does the formatter play with the Wini example from the one minute tutorial section http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/OneMinuteTutorial.java.html

Comment: I never used that framework, but from JavaDoc then Wini inherit from Ini and there you have method Ini#setConfig(Config). I think that when you set the config to it like to formater then the result should be as expected.

Comment: I used `config.setStrictOperator(true)`. The spaces around = are removed. But I have many \\ inserted around semicolons. How do I get rid of \\?