# How to get rid of spaces when using the ini.store() method to write into ini files?

Tags: java, ini, ini4j

I am using the Java API [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) to parse ini files. My original .ini file has the following key-value format:

```
[section]
key=value
```

where no spaces are around the = character.

But after after using the `ini.store()` method to save changes into the file (where ini is the Ini object referencing my .ini file), the content in the .ini file becomes

```
[section]
key = value
```

where extra spaces are inserted around the = character. I am not sure if I am using the `store()` method correctly. Is there a way to get rid of the spaces?

---- Update ----

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859328/java-ini-without-spaces), I have inserted the following lines in my code:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setStrictOperator(true);
ini.setConfig(config);
```

The spaces are removed. But I have a new problem with the semicolons:

```
# before
[bashful]
weight = 45.7
height = 98.8
age = 67
homePage = http://snowwhite.tale/~bashful
homeDir = /home/bashful

# after
[bashful]
weight=45.7
height=98.8
age=67
homePage=http\\\://snowwhite.tale/~bashful
homeDir=/home/bashful
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ini without spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859328/java-ini-without-spaces)

Comment: Please see my updates. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved the problem. Post my own solution for future reference:

To get rid of spaces before and after =, need to use:

```
Config config = ini.getConfig(); // instead of Config config = new Config()  
config.setStrictOperator(true);
ini.setConfig(config);
```

Make sure you are using Wini, not Ini. If you use Ini and config.setStrictOperator(true), the problem is that you will see extra back-slashes inserted before some special characters such as `:`, `"`, etc. Simple fix is to change Ini to Wini:

```
Wini ini = new Wini(new File(filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set escape to false when using Ini4j on Linux to resolve it:

```java
Config.getGlobal().setEscape(false);
Config.getGlobal().setStrictOperator(true);
Ini ini=new Ini(yourFile);
```